# SET label : pass label name as parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jrestclient

I have a query like this:

> unwind {data} as row with row MERGE (p:Book{guid:row.bookGuid}) set p.name=row.name, p:Science

I want to pass the label 'Science' as a parameter as this label is not same for all the rows which I am passing in {data}.

I tried below query, but this is throwing syntax error.

> with parameter like: { guid:1, name:"testName1",label1:"Histroy"}
>
> unwind {data} as row with row MERGE (p:Book{guid:row.bookGuid}) set p.name=row.name, p:row.label1

Any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Just came across this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274364/in-neo4j-how-to-set-the-label-as-a-parameter-in-a-cypher-query-from-java    --Not yet supported?

Comment: "Parameters can not be used as for property names, relationship types and labels, since these patterns are part of the query structure that is compiled into a query plan."  http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.6/cypher-parameters.html

Comment: Not yet but hopefully soon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) `apoc.create.addLabels()`:

```
UNWIND {data} as row WITH row
MERGE (p:Book{guid:row.bookGuid})
SET p.name=row.name
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(p), [row.label1])
```

Another example:
[Using Cypher and APOC to move a property value to a label](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_cypher_and_apoc_to_move_a_property_value_to_a_label)

Answer (score 1):

Yeh it's not supported yet. If you want to make it work you have to do a bit of a hack using FOREACH which you'll have to do for each type of label:

```
unwind {data} as row with row 
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN row.label = "Science" THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
    MERGE (p:Book:Science{guid:row.bookGuid}) 
    set p.name=row.name
)

FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN row.label = "Math" THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
    MERGE (p:Book:Math{guid:row.bookGuid}) 
    set p.name=row.name
)
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you could structure your data differently:

```
(:Book {guid, name})-[:HAS_LABEL]->(:Label {name})
```

In this way you could use the label name as parameter in CREATE or MATCH queries. Your original query would be:

```
UNWIND {data} as row WITH row 
MERGE (p:Book {guid: row.guid})
MERGE (l:Label {name: row.label})
CREATE UNIQUE p-[:HAS_LABEL]->l
SET p.name = row.name
```

Comment: Yes but that would defeat the advantage of using the Neo4j labels as a convenient and fast way of accessing your data if you always have to go through the category node. In some cases this is useful though (hierarchies of labels).

Comment: Yes, it would be slower like this (although indexing Labels by name should make it fast enough), but I think that, in this case, Book label is not meant to be a node label. IMO, neo4j node labels should be like OOP classes, and Book label is more like a field.